# How to take a picture of a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have an app where I want to take a screenshot of a UIView when I am in another view. I have 4 views on one of my pages that can be toggled using a segmented control. But I want bmy view in the second segment to e displayed when I am in the first segment. Is there any way that I can do this?

This is what I have used so far:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];        
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGRect rect;
rect=CGRectMake(0, 120, 320, 560);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
Screenshot = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

return Screenshot;
```

This gets me the screenshot of the view I currently am in.
What I want to do is to take a screenshot of the second view while in the first view.

This is what I changed:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(View2.bounds.size);
```

For some reason this is not working? Can you tell me why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];` to `[self.view2.layer renderInContext:context];`

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(View2.bounds.size);` Only specifies the bounds to render the view!